# What is the best way to store Date in savedInstanceState?

Tags: android, date, time, storage, store

I am using the onSaveInstanceState method to store and retrieve local variables inside a fragment.
I have the following code (simplified) in one of my fragments :

```
private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm");
private Date myDate;

public Date getDate() { return myDate; }

public void setDate(Date date) { this.myDate = date; }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

    TextView tvDate = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview_date);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        try {
            myDate = dateFormat.parse(savedInstance.State.getString("DATE"));
        catch (ParseException e) {
        }
    }

    //myDate is being set by a different fragment using the setDate method

    if (tvDate != null)
        tvDate.setText(dateFormat.format(myDate));

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putString("DATE", dateFormat.format(myDate));
}
```

This way I can store and retrieve the date value when my view gets destroyed and recreated, by rotating the screen for example, which is was the main problem.
This works, but I can tell this isn't efficient. If I store more variables like this, the view creation is taking much longer (a few seconds to load for 10 variables containing strings and booleans).

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Hard to believe. Ten variables is nothing. What kind of difficult things are you doing meanwhile?

Comment: There's something else wrong with your code if 10 variables take a few seconds to load from the `Bundle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not seem to cause performance issues and is the normal and efficient way to store your state on Android. I've added some comments/adjustments to your code below however which might tackle other errors or could speed things up.

```
    private static final String STATE_DATE = "state:date";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, e Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

        TextView tvDate = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview_date);

        // Check if the savedInstanceSTate contains the date String key.
        if (savedInstanceState != null
                && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_DATE)) {

            try {
                // Consider doing complex tasks like parsing etc. in the background.
                // Parsing a date shouldn't be the issue here but doing many things like this may 
                // be the cause of the performance issue. 
                myDate = dateFormat.parse(savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_DATE));
                catch(ParseException e){
                }
            }

            //myDate is being set by a different fragment using the setDate method

            if (tvDate != null)
                tvDate.setText(dateFormat.format(myDate));

            return rootView;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        // Remove the date formatter here. Try to format your date immediately when storing it in the variable.
        // When restoring your date from your savedInstanceState you're already formatting it.
        savedInstanceState.putString(STATE_DATE, myDate);
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

`Date` is `Serializable`. Stop converting it to and from strings. Just put it in the `Bundle` directly, using [`putSerializable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable)), retrieving it via [`getSerializable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference,/android/os/Bundle.html#getSerializable(java.lang.String)).

If that does not address your underlying performance concern, use development tools, such as method tracing in your IDE, to determine where you are spending your time.

Comment: do i have to cast it to (Date) while doing getSerializable() ?

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal: If the IDE says that you do, you do. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Android also use onSavedInstanceState() method to saved its state, like state of fragment when activity get destroyed and also there are some widget which saved its state like **EditText**, we don't need to save state of Edittext, Android take care of that with the help of onSavedInstanceState().

So I just want to tell you that its efficient way to save state.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly like others have already specified I don't think ten variables should cause an issue. There is definitely something else that's causing the lag.

Secondly an easier and efficient way would be to use the `date.getTime()` long value rather than parsing your date string for the same and restore it likewise.

At the cost of reiterating,  your lag is due to something else. You can verify this by logging the time it takes for each lifecycle even to complete and figure out the culprit.